# Twitter clone - how to stop my sidebar from moving down when I add other content

Tags: html, css

I am creating a Twitter clone but the sidebar moves down when I create the main page contents. I tried using Position - fixed and relative but still the same issue. Before I added the main page content, the sidebar was correctly positioned ([please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsJv9.png)) but as soon as its added, the sidebar moves down([please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwK9c.png)).

I'm using Grid to create the three columns to give the Twitter aesthetics.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.twitter-logo {
  height: 28px;
  filter: invert(52%) sepia(50%) saturate(2964%) hue-rotate(179deg) brightness(95%) contrast(97%);
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.left-sidebar {
  /* position: fixed; */
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  background: rgba(29, 161, 242, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #1da0f2;
  margin-right: 23px;
  /* padding: 20px; */
}

.left-sidebar-menu {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(15, 20, 25);
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.left-sidebar-menu-icon {
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 26px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background: rgba(29, 161, 242, 0.1);
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #1da0f2;
}


/* --------------------------------MAIN PAGE------ */

.main-page-header {
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.main-page-header-profile-picture {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 48px;
}

.main-page-input {
  border: 0 solid black;
}

.main-page-input-box {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.main-page-tweet-box {
  margin-top: -5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  outline: none;
}

.main-page-tweet-box:focus main-page-tweet-box:hover {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}

.main-page-tweet-box {
  height: 130px;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  /* position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px; */
}

.main-page-input-privacy {
  /* display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start; */
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1da1f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-page-input-privacy-icon,
main-page-input-privacy-text {
  display: inline;
}


/* .main-page-input-privacy i{
    float: left;
} */

.main-page-input-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: -35PX;
}

.main-page-input-icons-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.main-page-input-icons li {
  display: inline;
  /* width: 300px; */
  list-style: none;
  color: #1da1f2;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-page-tweet-button {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1da1f2;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* width: 75px; */
  /* height: 30px; */
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* .main-page-input form {

} */


/* .left-sidebar-menu-icon-active using js {
    filter: invert(52%) sepia(50%) saturate(2964%) hue-rotate(179deg) brightness(95%) contrast(97%);

} */


/* .left-sidebar-menu-btn {

} */

.tweetbox__input img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}

.tweetBox {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 8px solid var(--twitter-background);
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.tweetBox form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tweetbox__input {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tweetbox__input input {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.tweetBox__tweetButton {
  background-color: var(--twitter-color);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.tweet {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(47, 51, 54);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tweet-author-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.tweet-feed-content {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.tweet-header {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.tweet-author-username {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  /* color: rgb(231, 233, 234); */
}

.tweet-author-handle {
  color: rgb(113, 118, 123);
}

.tweeted-time {
  color: rgb(113, 118, 123);
}

.engagement-icons-ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 navbar">
      <nav>
        <div class="left-sidebar">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src={ % static 'network/images/brand.svg' %} alt="Twitter logo" class="twitter-logo">
          </a>
          <ul class="nav flex-column left-sidebar-menu mb-4 mt-2">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src={ % static 'network/images/all-post.svg' %} alt="All post" class="left-sidebar-menu-icon"> All Post
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src={ % static 'network/images/following.svg' %} alt="Following" class="left-sidebar-menu-icon"> Following
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src={ % static 'network/images/notifications.svg' %} alt="Notifications" class="left-sidebar-menu-icon"> Notifications
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src={ % static 'network/images/messages.svg' %} alt="Messages" class="left-sidebar-menu-icon"> Messages
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src={ % static 'network/images/profile.svg' %} alt="Profile" class="left-sidebar-menu-icon"> Profile
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src={ % static 'network/images/more.svg' %} alt="More" class="left-sidebar-menu-icon"> More
              </a>
            </li>
            <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill my-2 py-3">Tweet</button>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="main-page-header mt-3 sticky-top">Home</div>
      <div class="main-page-input">
        <!-- <form class="d-flex flex-column"> -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2 main-page-header-profile-picture">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a6/58/32/a65832155622ac173337874f02b218fb.png" class="main-page-header-profile-picture" alt="profile-picture" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <div class="main-page-input-box">
              <div>
                <textarea name="tweet-box" id="" class="form-control main-page-tweet-box text-wrap" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="What's happening"></textarea>
                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control main-page-tweet-box text-wrap" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="What's happening"> -->
              </div>
              <div class="main-page-input-privacy pb-2 mt-3">
                <i class="fas fa-globe-americas main-page-input-privacy-icon"></i>
                <span class="ain-page-input-privacy-text ml-2">Everyone can reply</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-page-input-icons mt-3">
              <ul class="main-page-input-icons-ul">
                <li><i class="fa-solid fa-image"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa-solid fa-face-grin"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i></li>
              </ul>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill px-4 main-page-tweet-button"><strong>Tweet</strong></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- </form> -->
      </div>

      <div class="tweet-feed">
        <div class="tweet">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/140/140/people" alt="author profile picture" class="tweet-author-image" />
          <div class="tweet-feed-content">
            <div class="tweet-header">
              <a href="#" class="tweet-author-username">Nick Huber</a>
              <div class="tweet-author-handle">@sweatystartup</div>
              <div class="tweeted-time">8h</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tweet-content">
              <div class="tweet-created-content">It is a wonderful day</div>
            </div>
            <div class="engagement-icons">
              <ul class="engagement-icons-ul">
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa-solid fa-retweet"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-from-bracket"></i></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tweet">
          <img src="http://placeimg.com/140/140/animals" alt="author profile picture" class="tweet-author-image" />
          <div class="tweet-feed-content">
            <div class="tweet-header">
              <a href="#" class="tweet-author-username">Randall</a>
              <div class="tweet-author-handle">@RandallKanna</div>
              <div class="tweeted-time">18h</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tweet-content">
              <div class="tweet-created-content">Hey friends</div>
              <img src="http://placeimg.com/300/300/tech" alt="tweeter feed" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      TODO
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```